# StoryBoard API in Corona

Tags: storyboard, coronasdk, scene

I am trying to use StoryBoard API in Corona. However, my button touch event is not working at all. Can you look at my code and help me out?

main.lua :

```
     local storyboard = require "storyboard"

     storyboard.gotoScene( "scene1", "fade", 500 )
```

scene1:

```
     local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
     local scene = storyboard.newScene()


     local image

     -- Touch event listener for background image
      local function onSceneTouch( self, event )
  if event.phase == "began" then

    storyboard.gotoScene( "scene2", "fade", 400  )

    return true
        end
      end


     -- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
    function scene:createScene( event )
local screenGroup = self.view

image = display.newImage( "bird.png" )
screenGroup:insert( image )

image.touch = onSceneTouch


print( "\n1: createScene event")
   end

   function scene:enterScene( event )

print( "1: enterScene event" )

  end

    function scene:exitScene( event )

    print( "1: exitScene event" )

   -- remove touch listener for image
image:removeEventListener( "touch", image )

  end


   -- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)
   function scene:destroyScene( event )

print( "((destroying scene 1's view))" )
  end


   scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

   scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

   scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

   scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )


   return scene
```

And my second scene is same like that. However when i touch on the image, it does not go to second scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to add the event listener to your image.

Comment: Thank you, royi. I just didn't know this second format of event listener. I should have added this one to the code: image:addEventListener( "touch", image )

Answer (score 2):

```
local function onSceneTouch( self, event )
  if event.phase == "began" then
    storyboard.gotoScene( "scene2", "fade", 400  )
    return true
  end
end
```

change '**return true**' to '**return false**' in onSceneTouch function before assigning any event to image, etc